# how to change element of struct in a list c#?

Tags: c#, struct

```
public struct rectangle
{
   public decimal a;
}
```

that is my struct 
and i have a list of struct rectangles

```
list<rectangle> dataRectangle= new list<rectangle>();
```

now i have already added some structs into the list
now i would like to change the value of a struct present in a list like

```
dataRectangle[0].a=0;
```

it says

```
cannot modify the return value ' list<form4.rectangle>.this[int] ' because it is not a variable
```

help why is this coming and is there another way to modify

Comment: If you really want to put mutable structs in a container, then use `array`. Everything else (list, etc) is just a pain.

Comment: SOme duplciates here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526/changing-the-value-of-an-element-in-a-list-of-structs, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679033/cannot-modify-struct-in-a-list. Why use a struct if you want to mutate it?

Answer (score 2):

A `struct` is a **value type**. So in contrast to a *reference* type like a `class` you don't pass around references to an instance, but pass around the *value* itself.

So what is returned from the indexer `dataRectangle[0]` is not a reference to your `struct` but a **copy** of that `struct`. And it's simply passed on the stack but is no variable itself.

To solve this, you can either declare your `rectangle` as `class` (which I would prefer for a *mutable* type:

```
public struct rectangle
{
   public decimal A {get; set;}
}
```

or you would (as ugly as it looks) have to do a reassignment like

```
dataRectangle[0] = new rectangle{a=0};
```

Comment: Can we please simply close the question as duplicate? We don´t want those simple question that have been answered thousand of times before here on SO

Comment: @HimBromBeere I agree and already voted to close. I just can't get used to _first_ look for duplicates instead of simply answering. Anyway those questions are still search anchors to lead asking users to answers, so I don't think it's harmful to SO to leave this answer now. And I promise to try to remember to check for duplicates before answering in the future.